# What is the timeline for OpenShift Origin 4.X?

Tags: okd, openshift-4

My company is playing around with OKD. I got a question as to when version 4.1 would be available for the public. Any comment in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer too!

Comment: This blog post may worth reading [OpenShift Commons Briefing: OKD4 Release and Road Map Update with Clayton Coleman (Red Hat)](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-commons-briefing-okd4-release-and-road-map-update-with-clayton-coleman-red-hat/) especially, its additional links.